# laravel redirect->back() not providing me with a valid url

Tags: php, laravel

So in one of my views I am generating a redirect()->back()->with() command to send the user back to a previous page.

```
 <a  href="{{ redirect()->back()->with('redirectRewards', true)}}"><button>Go Back</button></a>
```

the issue I run into is that it does not provide me with the url. This is what I get.

```
 http://localhost:8888/pp/public/HTTP/1.0%20302%20FoundCache-Control:%20no-cacheDate:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20
%20%20Tue,%2024%20Nov%202015%2022:23:12%20GMTLocation:%20%20%20%20%20%20http://localhost:8888/pp/public/task/matching/response/house%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%20%20%20%20%3Chead%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset=%22UTF-8%22%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20http-equiv=%22refresh%22%20content=%221;url=http://localhost:8888/pp/public/task/matching/response/house%22%20/%3
E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3ERedirecting%20to%20http://localhost:8888/pp/public/task/matching/response/house%3C/title%3E%20%20%20%20%3C/head%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cbody%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Redirecting%20to%20%3Ca%20href=%22http://localhost:8888/pp/public/task/matching/response/house%22%3Ehttp://localhost:8888/pp/public/task/matching/response/house%3C/a%3E.%20%20%20%20%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E
```

So I'm thinking I am using the function wrong but how can I simply get a back() url to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you probably want to use is [`URL::previous()`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_previous).

```
 <a href="{{ URL::previous() }}">Go Back</a>
```

The `redirect()->back()` method actually calls the `URL::previous()` method to create the `RedirectResponse`.

Comment: Would I be able to send a session with that as well? I need my controller to notice that it's not business as usual and that it came from there too. Is there a way?

Comment: No, not with this method. I'm not sure if there is a way to do that. Unless someone else can come up with another method, my suggestion would be to use query parameters instead.

Comment: Actually. I've managed to switch my script a little bit to make it work! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`redirect()` does generate a URL.  It returns an instance of `Illuminate\Routing\Redirector`.  It's meant for use within a Controller Method or a Route Closure.

You want the `route()` [helper method](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-route)

`$url = route('routeName');`

Comment: Well I the problem I have with this is that I need go back to the previous page. Many pages can lead to this page and it needs to go back to that given controller. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `redirect()` cannot be used after printing any output, it will not work.
If you want the link to go back. Just use simple JS script, as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp).

Comment: The thing with this is that I wouldn't necessary go back. Rather I used the back()-> with the session to then redirect to the proper place in my controller. since the previous page is actually for something else but is related

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
{{ Request::referrer() }}
```

you can achieve the same by using just PHP (but I prefer the Laravel's syntax since it's more readable and clean :

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]
```